# Linking work items to published tests in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, mstest, workitem

**Is there a way to add link to work item referencing published test result in TFS 2010?**

What I wanna do:

1. Run tests in Visual Studio.
2. Publish results to some existing build.
3. Open some work item and add link to the published test results.

This was possible in TFS 2008. As for TFS 2010 I tried to do this using VS 2008 and VS 2010. VS 2008 has disabled "Browse" button when I select link type "Test Result". VS 2010 says I should open test result and create a link from there. But when I use "Add to Work Item ..." test result is added as file to Attachments of the work item instead of just a link.
I also tried to use TFS API to manually add link the same way I did it for TFS 2008. Link is added but when I try to follow the link in VS it says that referenced test result is not present in TFS.
This looks strange cause there is link type "Test Result", so I assume it's possible to add such link somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way Microsoft describes what you are asking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182501.aspx